# selecting an input by a specific class; single call possible

Tags: jquery

I'd like to target a specific checkbox such as the 'is-wine' below but am not sure the syntax and ideally if it can be done in a single line.

Any ideas on how to do this? Basically just want to select the 'is-wine' checkbox and not the others.

thx

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.click-me').on('click',function(){
 // doesn't work
 //$('.chex input .is-wine').attr('checked',status);  
   $('.chex input').each( function() {
      $(this).attr('checked',status);
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
here i am withing sub
<div id='my-killer-id'>
  <div class='click-me'>clicke me for is-wine</div>
  <div class='chex'>
  <input type='checkbox' class='is-wine' /><br />
  <input type='checkbox' class='is-coffee' /><br />
  <input type='checkbox' class='is-tea' /><br />
  <input type='checkbox' class='is-cocktail' /><br />
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be without the space..

```
$('.chex input.is-wine').attr('checked',status);
```

If you place a space there it will go to the child of the input (which has no children)

```
if($('.chex input.is-wine').is(':checked')){
        alert('is wine is Checked !!')
     }      
     else{
       alert('is wine is not Checked !!')
    }
```

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/bFbL3/)

You can come up with multiple selectors for this .. As the class is unique

```
$('.chex .is-wine').attr('checked',status); 

OR 

$('.is-wine').attr('checked',status); 

OR

$('.chex input[type=checkbox][class=is-wine]').attr('checked',status);
```

Comment: cool, this looks right. working on the toggling of it now. Have to wait a few minutes to accept. thx